# SELENIUM PYTHON IFRAME - Acceptance of cookies

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I hope you might help me out with the simple/not simple code to accept the cookies on one of the sites. The popup is in iframe. I was trying to figure it out but cannot find the reason why does it not work.

My code:

```
import time
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

@pytest.fixture
def driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()

def test_if_cookies_are_accepted(driver):
    driver.get('https://diablochairs.com/en/')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "cmpbox")))
    button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cmpwelcomebtnyes > a')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
```

Comment: There is no IFRAME. You can just click on Accept all button directly, without worrying about any IFRAMES

Answer (score 0):

There is no IFRAME. You can just click on <kbd>Accept all</kbd> button directly, without worrying about any IFRAMES.

Code to click on <kbd>Accept all</kbd> cookies button:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://diablochairs.com/en/")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Accept all']"))).click()
time.sleep(10)
```